# Почему AsyncTask.onProgressUpdate() не разрешает менять текст в TextView?

Tags: android, многопоточность, android-asynctask

Код:

```
class AsyncProgressUpdate extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        loadingStatus.setText("Подготовка");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1_000);
            onProgressUpdate(1);
            for (int i=1; i<=4; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(1_000);
                onProgressUpdate(i*25);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        int currentProgress = values[0];
        String textLoading = "";
        switch (currentProgress) {
            case 1:
                textLoading = "Подготовка";
                break;
            case 25:
                textLoading = "Инициализация";
                break;
            case 50:
                textLoading = "Проверка пароля";
                break;
            case 75:
                textLoading = "Подготовка";
                break;
            case 100:
                textLoading = "Завершение";
                break;
        }
        progressBar.setProgress(currentProgress);
        loadingStatus.setText(textLoading); //выпадает ошибка
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "loading Finish", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        loadingStatus.setText("Test Text");
    }
}
```

Вызывается код стандартным:

```
new AsyncProgressUpdate().execute();
```

Ошибка:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
              Process: dev.jorik.lawlex, PID: 6238
              java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
               Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6357)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:874)
                  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17476)
                  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17476)
                  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17476)
                  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17476)
                  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17476)
                  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17476)
                  at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.requestLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:3172)
                  at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17476)
                  at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6871)
                  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4057)
                  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3915)
                  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3890)
                  at dev.jorik.lawlex.SplashActivity$AsyncProgressUpdate.onProgressUpdate(SplashActivity.java:80)
                  at dev.jorik.lawlex.SplashActivity$AsyncProgressUpdate.doInBackground(SplashActivity.java:46)
                  at dev.jorik.lawlex.SplashActivity$AsyncProgressUpdate.doInBackground(SplashActivity.java:35)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: А почему вы убрали код ошибки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прикрепили бы код ошибки. Вообще передавать данные в метод `onProgressUpdate` надо через метод `publishProgress`. А вы вызываете напрямую метод onProgressUpdate, который в вашем случае выполняется в бекграунд потоке. А с UI нельзя работать в бэкграунд потоке